# Export class from within a function in Typescript

Tags: class, typescript

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
loadDependency(function(dep){   
    //error, can't use export within a function
    export class MyClass {
        myF(){
            dep.myStuff();
        }
    } 
});
```

I can only create the class from a scope having access to `dep`.

The function `loadDependency` will only be called once. I want to keep using internal modules.

Is there any way to trick the compiler to achieve that?

My goal is to have auto-completion in other files. Ex: `var a:MyClass`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this `loadDependency`?

Comment: It loads the dependencies and return them in the callback. This is similar to AMD approach.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can "create" the classes in the module/namespace level and just instantiate objects of it when you get an instance of this `dep`, and so this will be something like:

```
export class MyClass {}

loadDependency(function(dep) {
    let myInstance = new MyClass();
    // do something with myInstance, MyClass and dep
});
```

And then you'll also be able to have access to `MyClass` from other files.

The reason that you can not `export` in your example is that the `export` only works in the context of module/namespace, it's a static declaration that tells the compiler that this class should be available from out side the module/namespace.

For example, this:

```
export class MyClass {}
```

compiles into:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var MyClass = (function () {
        function MyClass() {
        }
        return MyClass;
    }());
    exports.MyClass = MyClass;
});
```

And this:

```
module moo {
    export class MyClass {}
}
```

Into:

```
var moo;
(function (moo) {
    var MyClass = (function () {
        function MyClass() {
        }
        return MyClass;
    }());
    moo.MyClass = MyClass;
})(moo || (moo = {}));
```

(under target `ES5` and default module system, which is `CommonJS`).

What you tried to do is to export a class from within a function scope and that doesn't make sense.
What if this function will never be executed?

---

#### Edit

If you need the `dep` in the class then pass it as a parameter to the ctor:

```
export class MyClass {
    private dep: any;

    constructor(dep: any) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    myF() {
        this.dep.myStuff();
    }
}

loadDependency(function(dep) {
    let myInstance = new MyClass(dep);
});
```

If you have:

```
module MyModule {
    export class MyClass() { };
}
```

Then you can access the class with: `MyModule.MyClass`, but if you'd have:

```
module MyModule {
    export function myFunction() {
        export class MyClass() { };
    }
}
```

Then how would you access the class? it's not `MyModule.myFunction.MyClass` because that's only valid while myFunction is executed.  Same in your example.

Comment: That doesn't work if the class is created outside as it can't access `dep`. If the function is never executed, then there will be an error. But same goes for many other cases like adding `eval("return;")` anywhere in a module or hijack the results with `MyModule['MyClass'] = somethingElse` which is done frequently.

Comment: I edited my question to make the `dep` scoping problem more obvious.

Answer (score -1):

Trick the compiler.

```
var MyFunc = function(dep){ 
    if(!dep)
        return null;
    class MyClass {
        myFunc(){}
    }
    class MyClass2 {
        myFunc2(){}
    }
    return true ? null : {MyClass:new MyClass(),MyClass2:new MyClass2()};
}   

export var MyClasses = MyFunc(null);
loadDependency(myFunc);


var test:typeof MyClasses.MyClass = null; //has autocompletion
```